# owl-date-time : event is not trigerring on date time select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After selecting date time from owl date time picker event is not firing.

```html
<label style='margin-right:5px ;margin-left:210px'>
       Date Time:
       <input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt"  class="form-control" placeholder="Date time Picker" (change)="getScheduledTime($event)">
       <owl-date-time #dt ></owl-date-time>
     </label>
```

Comment: I think ngModelChange will work

Comment: I have added one working solution please check and let me know if any error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let Try this once, It's working fine tested,
Html File,

```
<input placeholder="Date Time:"
               [(ngModel)]="dateTime"
               [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt"
               (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" <!--here added -->
               >
```

Typescript,

```
onChange(data) {
    alert("Triggered" + data);
    console.log("Triggered", data);
  }
```

Screenshot,

[image]

I hope its solve your problem.

Thanks,

Muthukumar

Comment: from where it is taking seconds.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ngModelChange for this

```
(ngModelChange)="getScheduledTime($event)"
```